# Getting CORS error on Safari but working fine elsewhere

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I was building a small project nothing too complicated or complex, however I noticed I get an error while using **SAFARI** only

```
'[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://randomuser.me/api due to access control checks.'
```

I'm using NextJS and have uploaded my project to Vercel - https://rambolltest.vercel.app/dashboard

I'm using the randomuser API to generate random users like this -

```
async function getRandomUser() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api');
            const data = await response.json();

            return data.results;

        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are requested to many in same time

so user api server (https://randomuser.me/api) cloudflare sever return 503 status code

check cloudflare community

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-503-service-unavailable-service-temporarily-unavailable/44438